# styled(x) VS styled.x in styled component

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, styled-components

I'm new to using styled-component and i did read the styled component document and it said they do the same job , then why we use `styled(x)` if `Styled.x` is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

styled.x will only work if x is an html tag. If you want to style a component C, you would use styled(C), otherwise you would get an error because C is not a property of "styled" (you can't access styled.C)